# Upload a file and save it in database using row id in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, file-upload, phpmyadmin

I want to upload a file and save it in the database using "id" and enter the details in a table from the uploaded file. What are the controller and route codes that should use?
This is my code for the "form". It would be great if someone can answer as soon as possible.

```
<!-- Container (upload file) -->
 <div id="container" class="container text-center mx-auto ">
  <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="text-center">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Project Name">
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {{-- <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"> --}}
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="csv" name="csv">
        <label class="custom-file-label text-left" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks [image: form with the table]

Comment: Laravel does most of the work for you, and has documented it pretty well. Have you tried the official documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: @BenHillier I have. The thing is I'm totally new for PHP. I can't figure how to connect this HTML form with controllers and route methods.

Comment: @Perera i would recommend you to learn the framework

Comment: @KamleshPaul Ya i'm trying, but i need to submit this within today.

Comment: Please can anyone help?

Comment: @Perera this is not the right place

Comment: hi @Perera can you add your Controller code in question

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh I already did complete the code. Really appreciate your concern.